# Efficiency of Random.Next() vs Random.NextDouble()

Tags: c#, performance, random, time-complexity

I need to generate a random number between 0 and 1 in C#. It doesn't need to be more accurate than to a single decimal place but it's not a problem if it is.

I can either do `Random.Next(0, 10) / 10.0` or `Random.NextDouble()`.

I could not find any concrete information on the time complexity of either method. I assume `Random.Next()` will be more efficient as in Java, however the addition of the division (the complexity of which would depend on the method used by C#) complicates things.

Is it possible to find out which is more efficient purely from a theoretical standpoint? I realise I can time both over a series of tests, but want to understand why one has better complexity than the other.

Comment: Theory doesn't really matter so much as practical results. So if you're curious, use a [benchmarking library](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) to actually measure the performance difference.

Comment: 1. Run a benchmark to check 2. You can read source code for both implementations here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,c467f2953a8d2207

Comment: I think you're putting too much stress on efficiency here.

Comment: You only need 10 distinct values, easily fits in an array.  Not necessarily faster, you do have to measure.

Comment: Testing: no, about 18% slower than NextDouble().  This doesn't have to be optimized.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [implmenentation source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/random.cs), `NextDouble()` will be more efficient.

[`NextDouble()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/random.cs#L195-L197) simply calls the [`Sample()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/random.cs#L94-L119) method:

```
public virtual double NextDouble() {
    return Sample();
}
```

[`Next(maxValue)`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/random.cs#L181-L187) performs a comparison on maxvalue, calls `Sample()`, multiplies the value by maxvalue, converts it to `int` and returns it:

```
public virtual int Next(int maxValue) {
    if (maxValue<0) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxValue", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_MustBePositive", "maxValue"));
    }
    Contract.EndContractBlock();
    return (int)(Sample()*maxValue);
}
```

So, as you can see, `Next(maxValue)` is doing the same work as `NextDouble()` and then doing some more, so `NextDouble()` will be more efficient in returning a number between 0 and 1.

For Mono users, you can see [`NextDouble()`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.C5/C5/Random.cs#L62-L65) and [`Next(maxValue)`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.C5/C5/Random.cs#L94-L100) implementations here. Mono does it a little differently, but it basically involves the same steps as the official implementation.

As Zoran says, you would need to be generating a huge amount of random numbers to notice a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Either way, you'll be able to generate many many millions, if not billions, of random numbers every second. Do you really need that many?

On a more concrete level, both variants have time complexity `O(1)`, meaning that you could measure the time difference between the two methods and that would be it.

```
Random generator = new Random();

int count = 1_000_000;
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
double res;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    res = generator.Next(0, 10) / 10.0;
sw.Stop();

Stopwatch sw1 = new Stopwatch();
sw1.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    res = generator.NextDouble();
sw1.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} - {sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
```

This code prints 44 msec : 29 msec on my computer. And again - I don't think that you should optimize an operation which takes 44 milliseconds on a million executions.

If 15 nanoseconds per execution still makes the difference, then the second method is one tiny bit faster.